# Trace options enabling in yaffs

Tags: linux

I am using linux 2.6 and YAFFS.

In rcS script after mounting FS, I am passing tracing options to yaffs,

echo =none+error > /proc/yaffs

I wrote printk in yaffs_proc_write_trace_options to see the trace options passed.

static int yaffs_proc_write_trace_options(struct file *file, const char *buf,
                      unsigned long count, void *data)
In the above function, "buf" is the pointer to trace options.

I used printk(KERN_INFO,"%s", buf);

on the log file, I see
=none+error

7v9dl2

I am confused with second line printed the trace options because of which I am getting all trace logs.

Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

I was using busybox-1.18.5 version. I had upgraded the same to busybox-1.20.
I reverted back busybox version and it fixed this echo issue.